# How to display monitoring windows of Hawkular?

Tags: hawkular

I am a beginner to Hawkular and struggling to display the Hawkular web ui. My OS is Windows 10 and Cassandra datastax-ddc-64bit-3.7.0 is installed successfully.

Both Wildfly 10 and hawkular-services-dist-0.23.0.Final are unzip in c driver.

This is my Hawkular installation process.

1. add user in Hawkular home folder `<hawkular-services-dist-0.23.0.Final\bin>`

> add-user.bat -a -u username -p password -g read-write,read-only

2. execute standalone.bat in hawkular home folder <hawkular-services-dist-0.23.0.Final\bin>

> standalone.bat

3. I download hawkular-wildfly-agent-installer file from Wildfly agent Installer link of welcome windows, localhost:8080
4. I execute jar command like below

> java -jar hawkular-wildfly-agent-installer.jar —target-location=c:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final --username username —password password

5. And I start wildfly 10 with the following option in wildfly_home folder <c:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin>

> standalone.bat –Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100

6. These steps throw no exceptions. However I can not see any monitoring option display, only welcome window.

How can I display the Hawkular monitoring window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in GUI for showing metrics in Hawkular services. Hawkular exposes REST endpoints to fetch data, that you can directly use within an application of your own (they are detailed here: [for Metrics](http://www.hawkular.org/docs/rest/rest-metrics.html), [for Alerts](http://www.hawkular.org/docs/rest/rest-alerts.html)). But there's also a couple of available tools to display metrics:

- You can use [Grafana](http://grafana.org/download/) with the [Hawkular datasource plugin](https://grafana.net/plugins/hawkular-datasource).
- There's also [HawkFX](https://github.com/pilhuhn/hawkfx), a jruby client, but I'm not sure if it has been tested on windows.
- And an [Android client](http://www.hawkular.org/hawkular-clients/android-client/), though I never used it myself

Comment: Is there built in UI available in Hawkular APM?

Comment: Yes, Hawkular APM has its UI as you can see on screenshots here: http://www.hawkular.org/hawkular-apm/

Comment: However note that it is being replaced by jaeger: http://jaeger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Installed APM & it has UI but failed to fetch data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437065/hawkular-apm-not-showing-any-data.