# Hawkular APM not showing any data

Tags: wildfly, hawkular

We have installed Hawkular APM downloaded from https://github.com/hawkular/hawkular-apm/releases.

Then started the server:

```
bin/add-user.sh -a -u jdoe -p password -g read-write,read-only
bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.http.port={PORT} (1)
```

Then installed JVM agent on WildFly-8.2 server in the same machine. 
https://hawkular.gitbooks.io/hawkular-apm-user-guide/content/instrumentation/jvmagent.html

Copied apm folder to wildfly-8.2 and set setenv.sh.

```
apm/setenv.sh port
```

Then started WildFly. There is no data displayed in APM server. When I stopped APM server got following exception in WildFly-8.2 server which I want to monitor.

```
SEVERE: [AbstractRESTClient] [Thread[pool-2-thread-1,5,main]] Failed to get results
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

When I checked APM server didn't find any datasource connection.
Is there any more steps required?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the original Hawkular APM agent periodically pulls config information from the server, so by stopping the server it is failing to retrieve the config.

However Hawkular APM is no longer being actively developed as explained here: http://www.hawkular.org/blog/2017/04/19/hawkular-apm-jaeger.html.

So you may want to try an alternative solution.